# CURL Request Issue

Tags: php, curl, urlencode

So I'm a beginner to all of this.  I'm attempting to teach myself how to properly use CURL, and dabble a bit in API calls (don't worry, this question only relates to using CURL).

Now my original code worked just fine - I structured the request using urlencode, and the vast majority of requests leaded to the responses I was looking for.  About 10% of the received responses, however, that wouldn't retrieve the results I needed.  Let me give an example:

```
$urlToFetch = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/" . urlencode($objectURL) . "?" . $this->structureURL();
$response = ConnectionUtil::makeRequest($urlToFetch);
```

Using the above code would generate a $urlToFetch with the following data:
http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/www.alinki.com%2Fdomainlinks.php%3Fpage%3D516000?AccessID=XXXXXX&Expires=1286388878&Signature=YYYYYYYYY

This passes through CURL, and gets a response from the seoMoz API - the response, however, is missing some data.  I've poked around, and found that it is an issue with how the URL is structured.  For example, by changed the value from `www.alinki.com%2Fdomainlinks.php%3Fpage%3D516000` to `www.alinki.com/domainlinks.php?page=516000` I can retrieve all the fields I am looking for.  Going by that logic, I should be able to structure a URL similar to this:
(I'm removing the http since I cannot post more than one link) `lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/www.alinki.com/domainlinks.php?page=516000?AccessID=XXXXXX&Expires=1286388878&Signature=YYYYYYYYY`
and retrieve all the fields I need.  The problem is, when I attempt to pass that URL through to CURL, it will not complete the request.  Below is the code used for the CURL request:

```
public static function makeRequest($urlToFetch)
{
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "$urlToFetch");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, ConnectionUtil::CURL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
//var_dump($buffer);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$arr = json_decode($buffer);

return $arr;
}
```

And I request as follows:

```
 $urlToFetch = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/" . urlencode($objectURL) . "?" . $this->structureURL();
    $response = ConnectionUtil::makeRequest($urlToFetch);
```

Any ideas on what silly mistake I am making?

Comment: What do you mean by "Will not complete the request"? Curl fails? The remote server returns an error page instead of the data you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) instead of urlencode for generating your query string. It looks like the seomoz code is not handling the urlencoded data properly.